# Thread Synchronization and Thread Pausing\Resuming

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, ftp-client

I am trying to send the files from local to FTP, for that I am locking the TCPClient before sending the file. And that file sending is doing in another thread. So that the main thread doesn't affected.

As when I try to use the locked TCPClient before Unlocking it, it hangs. So how should I proceed, so that at the same time I can send the file also receive the file.(Both function are in different thread but locks the same TCPClient object).

I am also thinking to pause the first thread and perform second one, then when second complete and the after resume the first one.

Please help, I am lost in threads.

Comment: Please say which platform you're using... I've been assuming .NET based on the class name, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the same `TcpClient` from different threads to do different things - it represents a single connection, so the data sent and received on the two different threads would interfere with each other. (Even if you're "sending" a file in one and "receiving" a file in the other, both will need to send *and* receive data.)

I suggest you use two different `TcpClient` instances.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a bi-directionnal protocol. Even if you receive a file, you are sending acknowledgment all along. This means TCP works within a *context* : there is one receiver end, and one sender end.

You should not mix role within an instance. Use 2 different instances. They can work in parallel.